# Synchronizing between SQL Server and CSV file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv, synchronize

What is the better way to synchronize a table (customers), inside SQL Server and the customers inside an CSV file in Microsoft Excel?

Ok, here is the explanation:
I am developing a software in C#.NET 2008, and I create a table named Customers in SQL Server 2005. The contents of this table comes from a CSV file and the user can add more information because the SQL Table has more fields than CSV file.

The first time is easy.. I just ADDNEW for each line in CSV file.
But, the second time I cannot delete all table to import it again from the beginning because of these extra fields, so I need a method that can verify each record inside my SQL Table and CSV file automatically?  Or I need to treat the records one by one?

Comment: Do you have a key field in the CSV data? 

This is your initial problem, finding a way to match the records in the CSV with the data in the table.

Second problem is ensuring that the key in the CSV doesn't change or - less fun - working out how to manage the cases where it might have done.

Further to the last - there is a more general "what do I do if the record is removed from the CSV" question, not so much of an issue in your software as you can control the way deletion works.

Comment: I have a key field in the CSV data.
here is what I thinking to do:

1) C# will read each line of CSV and pass all columns to a stored procedure

2) procedure will ask for existing registry (using key field), and:

- it exists?
  . yes: update (doesn't matter if it was changed or not), and set to TRUE a field named UPDATED_BY_USER
  . don't: addnew

3) at the end of records in CSV, stored procedure will DELETE all records from customers where CHECKED = FALSE (this means that this record was deleted from CSV file), and after this will set to FALSE all records in customers table


Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SQL Server Integration Services, it can do everything you want to do and way more.

Alternatively, if you do want to code it, then I suggest making a hash of all fields in the CSV and using that to compare each row.  Different hash = change = updated row.

Comment: The notion of using a hash is neat (one of those ideas I "know" but that I can't seem to register in my head as a solution)

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the CSV table and the extra information into one table and one view.  You would have one table that is just a dumb mirror of the CSV file itself, and is easy to update:

```
    TRUNCATE TABLE csvmirror;
    BULK INSERT csvmirror
    FROM 'P:\ath\to\csvfile.csv' WITH
    ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
    , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' );
```

Then you create a view on that 'csvmirror' table that supplements the direct csv-file data with your extra data from the database.